# Heroku / Kotlin: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: java, spring, heroku, kotlin, jvm

I try to run kotlin spring webapp via `heroku run bash`. I run then:

```
java -cp ./build/libs/pss_kotlin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar pl.makzyt.pss_kotlin.MainKt
```

Then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at pl.makzyt.pss_kotlin.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I know I could run this if I get kotlin-runtime.jar. Is there possibility to obtain it with some command or should I download it manually?

EDIT

Here are my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',
            name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure',
            version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',
            name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',
            name: 'spring-boot-starter-web',
            version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.postgresql',
            name: 'postgresql',
            version: '42.2.2'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate',
            name: 'hibernate-core',
            version: '5.2.12.Final'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate',
            name: 'hibernate-entitymanager',
            version: '5.2.12.Final'

    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind',
            name: 'jaxb-api',
            version: '2.1'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',
            name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf',
            version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf',
            name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect',
            version: '2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a shadow jar

Answer (score 2):

If your spring boot app is configured correctly (spring boot plugin is applied in build.gradle) you just need to run the jar.

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

You don’t need to use the `-cp` option because Spring Boot repackages all dependencies in the jar that’s why you get a class not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting this error. But you might want to try generating a new Spring + Kotlin app from https://start.spring.io and copying the Maven dependencies/plugins into your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Here's an example https://github.com/jkutner/spring-boot-kotlin-starter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use Gradle and have similar dependencies (I edited the question), so I still don't know what might be wrong. Your code deploys fine though.